# If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is continuous, then $f$ must be constant

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Let $X$ be a connected topological space. Prove if $f:X\to\mathbb Q$ is continuous, then $f$ must be constant.

I know the definition of continuous is: for all $x\in X$ and all neighbourhoods $N$ of $f(x)$ there is a neighborhood $M$ of $x$ such that $f(M)\subseteq N$. This relates easily to the usual definition in analysis. Equivalently, $f$ is continuous if the inverse image of every open set is open. But I don't know how to relate this to the proof I need to come up with.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Q}$ with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yeah sorry I looked into the math thing and couldn't find out how to type it

Comment: the relative topology in Q inherited from R.

Comment: Assume that $f(X)$ contains two different $f(x)$ and $f(y)$. Can you find disjoint open sets $U,V$ covering $\mathbb Q$ such that each of these sets contains one of those points?

Answer (score 6):

The image of $f$ has to be connected. The only connected subsets of $\Bbb Q$ are points, as it is totally disconnected. So the image of $f$ is a point so it is constant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The continuous image of a connected space is connected (assume otherwise, find two disjoint open sets whose union is the entire image and use continuity to conclude a contradiction); every connected component in $\Bbb Q$ is a singleton.

Comment: if I assume f isn't constant, would I be able to use the intermediate value theorem or am I still totally off base?

Comment: @moe: Why does the intermediate value theorem hold here? We prove it for functions into $\Bbb R$. But continuity into $\Bbb R$ is not necessarily equivalent to continuity into $\Bbb Q$. If you prove that you can extend $f$ to a continuous function into $\Bbb R$, then you might be able to use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I was just assumeing that X is a subset in R...I was assumeing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove could be the following:

Assume $f$ is not constant so there are $a,b$ in $f(X)$ with $a\neq b$ and suppose $a <b$ , since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is connected then $f(X)$ is connected too.
Because $f(X)\subset\mathbb{R}$ for any $c$ s.t. $a<c<b$ then $c\in f(X)$(the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are exaclty the spaces) so $f(X)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ that contains a space, a contradiction.